# How to draw a half diagonal with one color and another half with another of navbar in css

Tags: css, css-shapes

I am using Bootstrap in conjunction with css and java script.
It is really hard for me to draw this background in css without affecting to the front code. In many questions people set width and height to 0%. But i cannot use this method of styling because of my navbar. And i am quite keen on to know how to attach my logo as my brand name in a transparent view. This image below clearly shows what i am trying to do:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient):

```css
.header {
  height:80px;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom left,blue 49%,transparent 51%);
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
</div>
```